# How to change my local git, after changing Bitbucket Repo to a project?

Tags: git, bitbucket

i have changed a Bitbucket GIT Repo to a project, so that it has been renamed to "projectname.reponame".

How can I update my local GIT Repo so that it now uses the new Repo name? Currently I cannot commit changes, as "I have no access" to the "old" Repo.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the remote via modifying your git config. The easiest way may be to edit it directly by opening `reponame/.git/config` in your favorite editor. Change the URL there to the new project URL and you should be able to push to it.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to edit `.git/config` directly - you can break the local copy of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote set-url origin https://server:port/new/repo/path`

Replace `origin` with the name of the remote, and `https://server:port/new/repo/path` with the new path for that remote.